# На утро или наутро?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Как правильнее?

1. В освободившейся комнате Алексей переночевал. А на утро (= на следующее утро) его ожидал сюрприз...
2. В освободившейся комнате Алексей переночевал. А наутро (= утром) его ожидал сюрприз...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Правильно **слитное** написание наречия ***"наутро"***, нет падежного управления для предлога ***НА***.
2. Сравнить: **отложить** (на что?) на утро. Нельзя сказать: **ожидать** (на что?) на утро. Правильно: ожидать утром.
3. Почему "на следующее утро"?  Могу предположить, что это **детерминант**, а он относится не к глаголу (**нет управления**), а к предикативной основе предложения.

[Ответ справочной службы на вопрос **№ 250294**](https://gramota.ru/spravka/vopros/250294)

Как пишется слитно или раздельно? Отложить (на) утро; (на) утро похолодало.

**ОТВЕТ**. Корректно: *отложить **на утро;** **наутро** похолодало.*

Comment: Спасибо за правку и за голос.